# What does app.ApplicationServices.GetService() do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

To read configuration we can use something like:

```
public class ConfigurationSample
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ConfigurationSample(IConfiguration configuration) =>
        _configuration = configuration;

    ...
}

// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ConfigurationSample>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Map("/ReadConfig", cfgApp =>
    {
        cfgApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            var configSample = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ConfigurationSample>();
            ... 
        });
    });
}
```

What I don't understand is, who pass the `configuration` object to `ConfigurationSample()` during `GetService()`? I couldn't find any documentation mentioning it.

Comment: `app.ApplicationServices.GetService` try to create an object of type which is passed between `<` and `>`. If tries to resolve the dependencies from the ones which are mapped in `IServiceCollection` in ConfigureService method and also the ones which are inbuilt mapped such as `IConfiguration`. `IConfiguration` is mapped to a `Configuration` type which internally takes care of loading `appSettings.json` file.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya How does `IConfiguration` get mapped to "a Configuration type"? It looks like just a simple Interface.

Comment: Is it because somewhere in .net's code, there is something like `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration, Configuration>();`?

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes, I think it's because the DI automatically creates the `configuration` object when the `IConfiguration` need to be instantiated.

Comment: Yes you could to that, `app.ApplicationServices.GetService()` service fetching that information actually which are instanciated.